# Changing Table's tr:even with a different background color

Tags: javascript, css

I know how to do this with jquery, by doing this:

`$("#rateTable tr:even").css("background", "#e7edea");`

However, the format I am using will not allow jquery. I tried the code below, but it is saying that the style is null. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
document.getElementById("rateTable tr:even").style.background = "#e7edea";
```

```html
<table id="rateTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>Purple</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Teal</td>
    <td>Yellow</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `getElementById` needs an ID, not a selector. Also, why aren't you just using CSS for this? `#rateTable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #e7edea
}`

Comment: Should be `document.querySelectorAll("#rateTable tr:nth-child(even)")` ... and then you need to loop through the result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really need JavaScript for this. It could been done in plain CSS with the [nth-child pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #E7EDEA;
}
```

```html
<table id="rateTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>Purple</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Teal</td>
    <td>Yellow</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And what if dynamic changing is needed?

Comment: No dynamic change will be needed for this instance. I had no idea I could do it with CSS, so this is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `querySelectorAll` and next iterate over received collection to change background. See below:

```
var trToChange = document.querySelectorAll("#rateTable tr:nth-child(even)");

for(var i = 0; i < trToChange.length; i++){
    trToChange[i].style.background = "#e7edea";
}
```

Comment: Should be `querySelectorAll("#rateTable tr:nth-child(even)")`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `#rateTable tr:nth-of-type(even)` as your selector. `document.selectElementById()` only works when you give it the exact string being used as an id, not a CSS selector. I would do it with CSS because it will update automatically and is likely faster, but you can do it in JS if you want:

```js
const evenRows = document.querySelectorAll("#rateTable tr:nth-of-type(even)")
for (const row of evenRows) row.style.background = "#e7edea"
```

```html
<table id="rateTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>Purple</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Teal</td>
    <td>Yellow</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Pink</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```